# the button is not doing its supposed function

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net

I'm having a project to create a website that connects my database to perform different functionalities. When I create the web form and connects it with the database, and when i click the button it's supposed that all the products will appear but it doesn't happen.

This is the SQL procedure:

```
    CREATE PROC reviewOrders
    AS
    BEGIN 
    SELECT * 
    FROM Orders 
    END
```

And this is the c# code

```
    protected void reviewOrders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("reviewOrders", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

    }
```

and the HTML code:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReviewOrders.aspx.cs" 
     Inherits="GUCommerce.ReviewOrders" %>

     <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:Button ID="viewOrders" runat="server" OnClick ="reviewOrders" Height="45px" 
    Text="view orders" Width="148px" />
            </div>
            <p style="height: 121px">

            </p>
            <asp:Panel ID="x" Visible ="false" runat="server" Height="338px">
                <asp:Table ID="orders" CellPadding ="4" runat="server" Height="67px" Width="316px">
                </asp:Table>
            </asp:Panel>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can one please tell me what is missing?
Thanks is advance!

Comment: Looks like you're missing code to populate / fill your table with the results.

Comment: @dvo I'm totally new to C# and HTML so can you please help me with it?

Comment: There are plenty of different topics (on StackOverflow and by also doing a simple google search) consuming data....but if you think about it, what are you actually doing with the data after ````cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();```` because you need to then do something with that data.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` is used when not bringing back results.  You are bringing back results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `ASP Gridview` instead of `ASP Table`. Gridviews (`<asp:GridView>`) are used to present data in tables. They actually get rendered as html tables. Here is how to  build one using your code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="x" Visible="false" runat="server" Height="338px">
    <%--<asp:Table ID="orders" CellPadding="4" runat="server" Height="67px" Width="316px"></asp:Table>--%>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" CellPadding="4" runat="server" Height="67px" Width="316px"></asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Now, in the code-behind there are a couple changes. A `DataTable` can be used to store the results of your query and then you can bind a `DataTable` to a `GridView`. To do this, you need a `SqlDataAdapter` which is shown below.

```
protected void reviewOrders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // data table variable outside of sql block
    // you could also move the sql code to another method that returns a datatable
    DataTable dt = null;

    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConn"].ToString();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("reviewOrders", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        using (cmd)
        {
            conn.Open();

            // Use SQL Data Adapter instead of Execute Non Query
            using (SqlDataAdapter _Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                // Fill DataTable with results of query
                dt = new DataTable();
                _Adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }

    //

    gvOrders.DataSource = dt;
    gvOrders.DataBind();
}
```

Note: I use `using(SqlConnection)` and `using(cmd)` to handle closing the connection and command for me. Give this a shot.

Comment: Once you DataBind() the GridView, look at this reference to populate row data (either by BoundFields or specifying a TemplateField and the control you want in here): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @JohnPete22 Thanks for the reference. To OP - that is the preferred way to generate the columns of your table since it gives you a lot more control, but they should generate automatically based on the DataTable. You may need to add `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` to your GridView attributes

Comment: @dvo if the OP is using an RWD website then the GridView will break the layout as it generates a table automatically in the markup. In that scenario, a ListView would work better.